# Publish version programatically (like ClickOnce) whitout msbuild.exe

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, msbuild

I need to programatically publish a version (of software?), in the way ClickOnce is doing it. I have successfully done this by msbuild.exe:

msbuild /t:clean;publish /v:d /p:SolutionDir=D:\BuildOutputDirectory\ /p:PublishDir=D:\BuildOutputDirectory\ /p :PublishUrl=D:\BuildOutputDirectory /p:InstallUrl=D:\BuildOutputDirectory\ D:\Te mp\Unive.Net\Unive.Net\Unive.Net.csproj

In directory "BuildOutputDirectory" it has created a directory "Application files" and file setup.exe and file *.application.
Can someone guide me how to achieve the same with BuildRequestData class or similar?

Please anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
var globalProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms165431.aspx
    { "PublishDir", "BuildOutputDirectory\\" }
};
var projectInstance = new ProjectInstance(@"C:\Users\Ilya.Kozhevnikov\Dropbox\Unive.Net\Unive.Net\Unive.Net.csproj", globalProperties, null);

var buildManager = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager;
var buildParameters = new BuildParameters { Loggers = new[] { new ConsoleLogger() } };
var buildRequestData = new BuildRequestData(projectInstance, new[] { "Publish" });
var buildResult = buildManager.Build(buildParameters, buildRequestData);
```